# Как соединить массивы? (БЕЗ НУМЕРАЦИИ)

Tags: php

Помогите:
Возврощаяет

```
Array
(
[id] => 5
[count] => 1
)
Array
(
[id] => 10
[count] => 1
)
Array
(
[id] => 3
[count] => 1
)
Array
(
[id] => 8
[count] => 1
)
```

Нужно:

```
[0](
[id] => 5
[count] => 1
)
[1](
[id] => 10
[count] => 1
)
[2](
[id] => 3
[count] => 1
)
[3](
[id] => 8
[count] => 1
)
```

Мой код:

```
foreach ($in_cart as $key => $val) {
          $new_array = [];
          $new_array['id'] = $val['id'];
          $new_array['count'] = $val['count'];
          if($val['id'] == $id){
              $new_array['count'] = $new_array[$key]['count'] + 1;
          }
          print_r($new_array);
      }
```

Вот что содержит $in_card:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [count] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [count] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [count] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [count] => 1
    )
```

И ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО чтобы count + 1

Comment: Не надо писать в заголовках "решено", "не решено".

Comment: Хорошо. Только... Э... Оу ладно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этого достаточно:

```
foreach ($in_cart as &$val) {
    if ($val['id'] == $id) {
        $val['count'] += 1;
    }
}
print_r($in_cart);
```

Comment: В $in_card еще надо дописать. Спасибо за подсказку больше не нужно)